# how to configur sigar with libsigar-x86-linux.so automatically in maven project

Tags: maven, sigar

I'm using sigar API in maven project, I have add the sigar maven dependencies and `log4j` dependencies into the `pom` file, but when I build the project it gives the following error

```
DEBUG Sigar  - no libsigar-x86-linux.so in java.library.path
org.hyperic.sigar.SigarException: no libsigar-x86-linux.so in java.library.path
```

Error was fixed when I manually added the `libsigar-x86-linux.so` file into the maven local repo, How can it be automatically configured using `pom` file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is a problem with maven dependency plugin. You've to add .so type as included type like here:

```
 <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>         
        <execution>
            <id>native-dep</id>
            <phase>compile</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <stripVersion>true</stripVersion>
                <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/lib</outputDirectory>
                <includeGroupIds>org.hyperic</includeGroupIds>
HERE ->         <includeTypes>dll,so</includeTypes>
            </configuration>
         </execution>
         ...
     </executions>
 </plugin>
```